# Is the entropy a concave function of the number of particles $N_j$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose we have a thermodynamic system which has $c$ components and the number of particles of each component are $N_1\cdots N_j\cdots N_c$. Suppose that the only work coordinate is $V$. Then, according to [Callen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471862568) the entropy function 
$S(U, V, N_1,..., N_c)$ needs to be a concave function of $U$ and $V$ to ensure thermodynamic stability, but what about the $N_j$?

Does it also need to be a concave function of the $N_j$'s? Why/why not?

Comment: More on [concave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+concave+entropy)/[convex](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+convex+entropy) entropy.

Comment: I've looked at other answers/resources but I haven't found anything that mentions $N_j$